# zookeeper implements lock with just create()?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Can I implement lock using zookeeper with just create()?
e.g.

```
acquire() {
  while(1) {
    zk.create(lockPath, new byte[0], ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
    if (lockPath already exists) {
      Stat stat = zk.exists(lockPath, this);
      if (stat != null) {
        this.wait();
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

release() {
  zk.delete(lockPath, -1)
}
```

Is it right?

If it is, then what's the advantage of the official realization using sequence and ephemeral children nodes?

Answer (score 0):

What would trigger `this.wait()` to release? Except this aspect provided solution works with a couple of disadvantages:

- Lock is not fair: if multiple clients waits to acquire, a random one would capture the lock
- Extra lag is introduced: no notifications of node removal is used
- If applications fails, lock would left stale

There is a [recipe](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Locks) on a zookeeper's site:

> Clients wishing to obtain a lock do the following:
>
> 1. Call create( ) with a pathname of "*locknode*/lock-" and the
>    sequence and ephemeral flags set.
> 2. Call getChildren( ) on the lock
>    node without setting the watch flag (this is important to avoid the
>    herd effect).
> 3. If the pathname created in step 1 has the lowest
>    sequence number suffix, the client has the lock and the client exits
>    the protocol.
> 4. The client calls exists( ) with the watch flag set on
>    the path in the lock directory with the next lowest sequence number.
> 5. if exists( ) returns false, go to step 2. Otherwise, wait for a
>    notification for the pathname from the previous step before going to
>    step 2.
>
> The unlock protocol is very simple: clients wishing to
> release a lock simply delete the node they created in step 1.

Also I highly recommend [Apache Curator](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/index.html) - a widely used library above Zookeeper with lots of recipes implemented, including different kinds of locks

Comment: I intend to use a watch on lockPath to awake that 'wait', but I don't know if I make the code right.

"If applications fails, lock would left stale". You're right. I didn't think of that.

And One thing that comes to mind is that it will cause 'herd effect'.